# What are the consequences of turning iCloud Document and Data syncing off?

Tags: icloud, storage, ios, data

I have disabled Documents and Data syncing in iOS 7 to overcome the [sluggish keyboard issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102232/keyboard-extremely-sluggish-on-ios7-with-iphone-4s). But I wonder what the consequences of turning Docu and Data sync off are?

Answer (score 1):

The consequence is data stays the same on your Mac and isn't kept in sync with other devices that use iCloud sync.

You can test if this is the cause of slowness by just disconnecting from the network.

Turning off iCloud documents is simple though and you can always turn it on again if you find something else was causing the slowness or you wish to have an easier time getting files back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I don't know all the consequences, however what you are doing is localizing your files. A file on an iDevice stays on that device, and a file on a mac, stays on the Mac. That's not just with Apple apps (Pages, Numbers, TextEdit, Preview), but also with any iCloud-enabled app (Coda, Rapidweaver, etc. ). Of course, you can always copy files yourself between devices, so you are losing some functionality, but you won't be doing any major damage.. HTH